# Inicializar variable string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

¿Cómo puedo inicializar un string vacío cuyo valor es "" pero en esta línea de código:

```
Presenter.OnRazonSocialChanged(txtRazonSocial.Text);
```

Yo lo había solucionado en el constructor del Presenter de la siguiente manera:

```
public ProveedorPresenter(Proveedor model, ProveedorView view)
    {
        _model = model;
        _view = view;


        _model.RazonSocial = "";
        _model.DocumentoIdentidad = "";
        _model.Direccion = "";
        _model.Fijo = "";
        _model.Celular = "";
        _model.Representante = "";
        _model.Email = "";

        _view.Presenter = this;
    }
```

[image: Debe funcionar así]

Sin inicializar las variables como vacío, me da el siguiente error:
[image: Error]

Como verán dependo del evento TextChanged, ¿cual sería la solución?

Gracias a todos por responder, prometo mejorar la calidad de mis preguntas y dedicarle mas tiempo a elaborarlas. Gracias a todos ustedes logre solucionarlo de esta manera.

Cree un método en el Presenter que se llama Inicializar modelo

```
public void InicializarNodelo()
    {
        _model.RazonSocial = string.Empty;
        _model.DocumentoIdentidad = string.Empty;
        _model.Direccion = string.Empty;
        _model.Fijo = string.Empty;
        _model.Celular = string.Empty;
        _model.Representante = string.Empty;
        _model.Email = string.Empty;
    }
```

Y lo llamo en el load de mi Vista(formulario)

```
private void ProveedorView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter.InicializarNodelo();
    }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no esta clara porque no mencionas que es lo que tratas de hacer, pero al parecer está relacionada con esta pregunta: [Implementando patrón de diseño MVP](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11747/implementando-patr%C3%B3n-de-dise%C3%B1o-mvp). Por favor mejora esta pregunta incluyendo todo lo necesario aquí

Comment: Buenos días, ya modifique mi pregunta aclarando los problemas que tengo, por favor de liberar la pregunta.

Comment: Pero, en el constructor estas asignando `_model = model`, por qué inicializas abajo cada elemento de `_model`, está vacio?, estas "limpiando" los valores de `_model` antes de empezar a trabajar con el.

Comment: Algún moderador puede fusionar el tema anterior de Implementado patrón de diseño MVP con este, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pregunta parece estar relacionada con [Implementando patrón de diseño MVP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11747/implementando-patr%C3%B3n-de-dise%C3%B1o-mvp) así que voy a contestar teniendo en cuenta ese contexto.

Al parecer lo que tratas de hacer es asignar el string vacío a `txtRazonSocial.Text` y a la vez pasarlo al método `Presenter.OnRazonSocialChanged()`. Eso lo puedes lograr fácilmente con la sgte expresión:

```
Presenter.OnRazonSocialChanged(txtRazonSocial.Text = "");
```

o

```
Presenter.OnRazonSocialChanged(txtRazonSocial.Text = String.Empty);
```

Sin embargo según el sgte código de la otra pregunta.

```
public class ProveedorPresente
{
    private Proveedor _model;
    private ProveedorView _view;

    ...

    public void OnRazonSocialChanged(string razonSocial)
    {
        _model.RazonSocial = razonSocial;
    }

    ...
}
```

y su uso aquí

```
public partial class ProveedorView : Form
{
    public ProveedorPresente Presenter { get; set; }
    public ProveedorView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...

    private void txtRazonSocial_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter.OnRazonSocialChanged(txtRazonSocial.Text);
    }

    ...
}
```

No me queda claro porque quieres pasar el string vacío en el handler cada vez que se modifica la Razón Social, el objetivo del método `txtRazonSocial_TextChanged` es notificarle al `Presenter` que el valor del control ha cambiado y pasarle el nuevo valor para que este a su vez lo pueda setear en el `Model`.

En todo caso si quieres inicializar el control como string vacío lo deberias setear en `Proveedor` (model) antes de inicializar los controles con los valores del model.

Comment: Hola Carlos Muñoz, cuando no ingreso datos en los controles y doy de alta a un prroveedor me envia la info como null pero si no estoy enviando nada debe mandarlo vacio(""), la razón que hago esta prueba es que tengo una clase Validator que me manda una serie de mensajes a la presentación que indican los campos obligatorios que tiene que llenar, etc.

Comment: Carlos Muñoz, hay un detalle si no ingreso datos no se inicializan las variables, por que dependo del evento textchanged es por eso que obtengo null, ese es mi problema.

Comment: Por eso te decía que inicialices el modelo con los campos en "", no el formulario

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar **[null coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173224.aspx)** `??`

```
Presenter.OnRazonSocialChanged(txtRazonSocial.Text ?? "");
```

En caso de que la propiedad `Text` sea `null` usará la cadena vacía `""`.

Comment: Hola Enrique, justamente quiero hacer esto, si es null que mande vacio ""

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que deseas es validar el contenido del `TextBox`:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtRazonSocial.Text)) {
            // contenido del TextBox Vacio !
        }else{
Presenter.OnRazonSocialChanged(txtRazonSocial.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí va mi respuesta, basandome en las demas respuestas ([enrique7mc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1462/enrique7mc) y [Carlos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/20/carlos-mu%c3%b1oz)) *(No puedo ver la imagen)*

Tengo entendido que quieres prevenir que el `string` que envias por parametro a la función `OnRazonSocialChanged(string)` sea null.

Empecemos por decir que tienes esto:

```
public ProveedorPresenter(Proveedor model, ProveedorView view)
{
    _model = model;
    _view = view;


    _model.RazonSocial = "";
    _model.DocumentoIdentidad = "";
    _model.Direccion = "";
    _model.Fijo = "";
    _model.Celular = "";
    _model.Representante = "";
    _model.Email = "";

    _view.Presenter = this;
}
```

Donde estas asignando tu parametro `model` de tipo `Proveedor` al campo interno `_model` de la clase `ProveedorPresenter` y luego asignas todos los valores a `""`
Lo que practicamente no tiene sentido *(Al menos para mi)*, lo mas correcto sería crear un constructor de la siguiente forma:

```
public ProveedorPresenter(ProveedorView view, Proveedor model = null)
{
    _model = (model != null) ? model : new Proveedor();
    // ...
}
```

Donde asignas un parametro `model` con un valor por defecto `null` para que si no lo especificas en la llamada al constructor
le asigne al campo `_model` el valor de un nuevo proveedor, de forma que los valores van a estar inicializados a `""` *(Si así lo especificaste en el constructor vacio de `Proveedor`)*

Luego, en tu método `OnRazonSocialChanged(string)` haces esto:

```
public void OnRazonSocialChanged(string s)
{
    _model.RazonSocial = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) ? "" : s;
}
```

Y tendrás lo que necesitas para que no te deje el `string` como `null`.